# loop through a python list of tuples and change a value

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have this code

```
a=[(1,'Rach', 'Mell', '5.11', '160'),(2, 'steve', 'Rob', '6.1', '200'), (1,'Rach', 'Mell', '5.11', '160')]
```

I want to change the last name Rob to 'Roberto' if the id = 2
So my idea was to change the tuple to a list so it will be easy to make the change

I tried :

```
a_len = len(a)
count = 0
a_list = []
while(count < a_len):
     a_list.append(a[count])
     count ++

for x, element in a_list:
     if element[0] == 2:
          a_list[x] = Roberto
```

But this didn't work, do you guys have any idea how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does it:

```
a=[(1,'Rach', 'Mell', '5.11', '160'),(2, 'steve', 'Rob', '6.1', '200'), (1,'Rach', 'Mell', '5.11', '160')]

for i,e in enumerate(a):
    if e[0]==2: 
        temp=list(a[i])
        temp[2]='Roberto'
        a[i]=tuple(temp)

print a
```

Prints:

```
[(1, 'Rach', 'Mell', '5.11', '160'), (2, 'steve', 'Roberto', '6.1', '200'), (1, 'Rach', 'Mell', '5.11', '160')]
```

If you want a list comprehension, this:

```
>>> [t if t[0]!=2 else (t[0],t[1],'Roberto',t[3],t[4]) for t in a]
[(1, 'Rach', 'Mell', '5.11', '160'), (2, 'steve', 'Roberto', '6.1', '200'), (1, 'Rach', 'Mell', '5.11', '160')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for idx, row in enumerate(a):
    id, name, surname, valA, valB = row
    if id == 2 and surname == 'Rob':
        a[idx] = (id, name, 'Roberto', valA, valB)
```

Answer (score 2):

short answer

```
a_list = [(_id, first, 'Roberto' if (last == 'Rob' and _id == 2) else last, x,y) for _id, first, last, x, y in a ]
```

This is python's list comprehension, which is a great tool for python.

The above have the same meaning as following code:

```
a_list = []
for _id, first, last, x, y in a:

    if last == 'Rob' and _id == 2:
         last  =' Roberto'

    a_list.append((_id, first, last, x, y))
```

Comment: This must be absolutely cryptic for the OP =/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
a=[(1,'Rach', 'Mell', '5.11', '160'),(2, 'steve', 'Rob', '6.1', '200'), (1,'Rach', 'Mell', '5.11', '160')]

a_list = []
for ele in a:
    a_list.append(list(ele))

for ele in a_list:

    if ele[0] == 2:
        ele[2] = "Roberto"

print a_list
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it gave me an error,on this line  a_list.append(list(ele)). `List objecs is not callable`.

Comment: Bizzar... did you just copy this piece of code or you have other code segements where "list" is a variable?

Answer (score 1):

I am not super familiar with Python, but here

```
      for x, element in a_list:
           if element[0] == 2:
           a_list[x] = Roberto
```

you are not selecting the item from your list.
Try

```
      for x in a_list:
           if x[0] == 2:
           x[3] = Roberto
```

X selects the tuple in the list, and the brackets select the data inside the tuple.